# Finding the database name from tsql script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to programmatically find the database context from a tsql script? ie the context that changes when you add a USE .  I ask because I am not using a USE, and would like to find the database name the script is running on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select db_name()
```